# Matching lowercase string to unaltered object key

Tags: javascript, object, matching, lowercase

I want to match a lowercased string to an object key without altering the original key. Later I will use the key in its original shape. Is there a way?

```js
userInput = "SOmekey".toLowerCase();
data = {"SoMeKeY": "Value"};
if (data[userInput]) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        console.log('Unaltered data: ', key, value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so if you call [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) on a string, you aren't changing that string, you are creating a new one. So no need to worry about getting back to the original one.

```js
userInput = "SOmekey";
data = {"SoMeKeY": "Value"};

for (key in data){
  // Neither key or userInput are changed by creating
  // lower cased versions of them. New strings are created
  // and those new strings are used here for comparison.
  if(key.toLowerCase() === userInput.toLowerCase()){
    console.log(key, data[key], "| Original user input: ", userInput);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does require the cpu to do some iteration though, right?

Comment: @DIProgan Not sure what you mean. Any loop results in iteration. All operations are ultimately carried out the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Then just lower the case of the object keys to search :D

```js
userInput = "SOmekey".toLowerCase();
data = {"SoMeKeY": "Value"};

//object's keys except they are lowered as well
let loweredKeys=Object.keys(data).map(a=>a.toLowerCase())

//now for verification
if(loweredKeys.includes(userInput)){
  let keyIndex=loweredKeys.indexOf(userInput)
  let values=Object.values(data)
  let keys=Object.keys(data)
  console.log("Unaltered data: ",keys[keyIndex],values[keyIndex])
}
```